# How do I merge data from two hashes and remember which hash the original data came from?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I have two hashes:

```
skills => {"Slice"=>9, "Kick"=>2, "Angle"=>1, "Topspin"=>1, "Shorten Backswing"=>1, "Balance"=>1}
categories => {"Serve"=>8, "Forehand"=>7}
```

I need to return the keys associated with the largest three values between the two lists.
I also need to keep track of which hash that key came from.

Ultimately I need the above two hashes to yield:

```
"Slice"=>9, "Serve"=>8, "Forehand"=>7
```

and somehow need to know that `Slice` is a skill, and `Serve` and `Forehand` are categories.
Maybe something like:

```
"Slice"=>[9, "skill"], "Serve"=>[8, "category"], "Forehand"=>[7, "category"]
```

I think an effective way of doing this would be to change the value to an array, where the first object would be my integer value, and the second object would be either skill or category:

```
skills => {"Slice"=>[9, "skill"], "Kick"=>[2, "skill"], "Angle"=>[1, "skill"], "Topspin"=>[1, "skill"], "Shorten Backswing"=>[1, "skill"], "Balance"=>[1, "skill]}
categories => {"Serve"=>[8, "category"], "Forehand"=>[7, "category]}
```

Then merging the two:

```
all_objects => {"Slice"=>[9, "skill"], "Kick"=>[2, "skill"], "Angle"=>[1, "skill"], "Topspin"=>[1, "skill"], "Shorten Backswing"=>[1, "skill"], "Balance"=>[1, "skill"], "Serve"=>[8, "category"], "Forehand"=>[7, "category"]}
```

Then returning the objects with the hash keys with the highest value in the first object of the array, then using the second value to declare whether the object was a skill or category.

This, however, becomes very cumbersome and it feels like I'm missing some more elegant way of accomplishing a similar task.

Comment: It appears you're descending into data structure munging hell. I recommend creating a Player class to encapsulate the logic, provide names to the behaviors above, and simplify the code.

Comment: Think about your question; It really sounds like you're asking us to write your code for you, but you don't show what you've tried. "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)"

Comment: My apologies, I felt that my existing code would have just confused the reader as it was a big mess (which is why I posted here anyway).  Maybe it would have been better suited for codereview.stackexchange.com .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd probably try an object oriented approach. Something like:

```
class Base
  attr_accessor :name, :value

  def initialize(name, value)
    @name, @value = name, value
  end

  def inspect
    "#<#{self.class} name=#{name.inspect} value=#{value.inspect}>"
  end
end

class Skill < Base
end

class Category < Base
end

skills = [Skill.new("Slice", 9), Skill.new("Kick", 2), Skill.new("Angle", 1), Skill.new("Topspin", 1), Skill.new("Shorten Backswing", 1), Skill.new("Balance", 1)]
categories = [Category.new("Serve", 8), Category.new("Forehand", 7)]

(skills + categories).sort_by(&:value).reverse.first(3)
#=> [#<Skill name="Slice" value=9>, #<Category name="Serve" value=8>, #<Category name="Forehand" value=7>]
```

Comment: you could implement `<=>` in Base as well.